# parsley.js: Error trying to add custom validator

Tags: parsley.js

I am trying to add a custom validator

```
window.ParsleyValidator
  .addValidator('invalidWords', {
    requirementType: 'regexp',
    validateString: function(value, requirement) {
        console.log(value,requirement);
      return /^\b(?:Stadium|GT|BB|HB|Simul|VNOSE|LT|combination|LT1|SSGT|BW|HBS|simul|combo|2hbs|4d|lt2|theatre)\b$/i.test(value)
    },
    messages: {
      en: 'Invalid words detected.'
    }
  });
```

with HTML as...

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="company" data-parsley-group="eventinfo" id="Company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company" maxlength="60" tabindex="3" title="Company" parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-invalidwords="" value="#request.args.company#">
    </div>
</div>
```

I keep getting the error `Callback must be instanciated with a function` and I am not sure why. I am following the directions on the site. http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#custom
It also doesn't seem to trigger on keyup either.
using version `2.0.7`

Answer (score 2):

I noticed I was on an older version so I have updated to `2.2-rc4` and the issue seems to be resolved.